# How to make a PDF from an HTML template using Python and Flask without viewing in browser?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to develop a set of PDFs based on an HTML template using Flask package in python. Given below is the main code (runserver.py) to run the server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response
import pdfkit

path_wkthmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
options={'page-size':'A4', 'dpi':400, 'disable-smart-shrinking': ''}

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<name>/<location>')
def pdf_tempate(name, location):
    rendered = render_template('pdf_template.html', name=name, location=location)
    css = ['main.css']
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False, css=css, configuration=config, options=options)

    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=output.pdf'

    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Currently, the main.css file is empty and the HTML template code is as shown below:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>PDF Sample</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Your name is : {{ name }}</h1>
        <h3>Your location is : {{ location }}</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code base has the following folder structure:

```
|- runserver.py
|- main.css
|- templates
    |-pdf_template.html
```

When I run the server and enter the following web address: http://127.0.0.1:5000/John/NewYork, it creates a PDF template in browser with the name and location at the appropriate locations. Till this point, everything is working as expected.

The issue with the above code is that when I need to create a loop to produce 100s of PDF from that template, it always needs to first create it in the browser to download it further. Is there any way, that I can create these PDFs and store it in a folder without the need to go into the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use flask, I use django. But you should be able to solve your problem by making a `.zip` file. I've done this when exporting tons of txt and csv files, so I'm pretty sure pdf's should work for it too *(let me know)*.

You'll use `zipfile` from the Python standard library, and it should look something like the following. Obviously, replace the code from the ORM you're using, and give the proper response when a request is triggered. This is a Django example, but if you can do what you've done so far, this should be self explanatory:

```
import zipfile
from django.http import HttpResponse
from my_app.models import MyModel


def zip_files(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip')
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(response, 'w')   # write mode
    objects = MyModel.objects.all()    # get your objects from database
    for obj in objects:
        contents_of_file = obj.attribute    # depending on what's needed, you might want to do extra loops here
        zf.writestr(obj.attribute_for_naming_file + '.pdf', obj.contents_of_file)

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=my_special_zipfile.zip'
    return response
```